# How to Calculate Year over Year Percentage Change in Dataframe with Datetime Index based on Date and not number of Periods

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, percentage

I have multiple Dataframes for macroeconomic timeseries. In each of these Dataframes I want to add a column showing the Year over Year percentage change. Ideally I would do this with a for loop so I don't have to repeat the process multiple times. However, the series do not have the same frequency. For example, GDP is quarterly, PCE is monthly and S&P returns are daily. So, I cannot specify the number of periods. Since my dataframe is already in Datetime index I would like to specify that I want to the percentage change to be calculated based on the dates. Is that possible?

Please see examples of my Dataframes below:

```
print(gdp):
Date         GDP           
1947-01-01  2.034450e+12
1947-04-01  2.029024e+12
1947-07-01  2.024834e+12
1947-10-01  2.056508e+12
1948-01-01  2.087442e+12
                  ...
2021-04-01  1.936831e+13
2021-07-01  1.947889e+13
2021-10-01  1.980629e+13
2022-01-01  1.972792e+13
2022-04-01  1.969946e+13
[302 rows x 1 columns]

print(pce):
Date        PCE        
1960-01-01  1.695549
1960-02-01  1.706421
1960-03-01  1.692806
1960-04-01  1.863354
1960-05-01  1.911975
              ...
2022-02-01  6.274030
2022-03-01  6.638595
2022-04-01  6.269216
2022-05-01  6.324989
2022-06-01  6.758935
[750 rows x 1 columns]

print(spx):
Date          SPX     
1928-01-03    17.76
1928-01-04    17.72
1928-01-05    17.55
1928-01-06    17.66
1928-01-09    17.59
             ...
2022-08-19  4228.48
2022-08-22  4137.99
2022-08-23  4128.73
2022-08-24  4140.77
2022-08-25  4199.12
[24240 rows x 1 columns]
```

Instead of doing this:

```
gdp['GDP] = gdp['GDP'].pct_change(4)
pce['PCE'] = pce['PCE'].pct_change(12)
spx['SPX'] = spx['SPX'].pct_change(252)
```

I would like a for loop to do it for all Dataframes without specifying the periods but specifying that I want the percentage change from Year to Year.

Comment: I don't get what you try to achieve. You need a new column in each (?) of your 3 dataframes and that column contains the yearly rate of change of the individual dataframe? Or combine them somehow to one dataframe? Please explain that in more detail and provide the code you tried so far.

Comment: Hi Nadine. Thanks for the comment. I want a column in each of these Dataframes showing the Year over Year change for each of these datapoints. I listed the different dataframes to show that the frequencies are different, and as such I cannot just loop them with pct_change(12) which I would do only for monthly data. I am interested in calculating the percentage change based on the datetime index so that it can be applied to Dataframes with different frequencies. Does that make sense? Let me know if you require additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
d = {'Date': [ '2021-02-01',
               '2021-03-01',
               '2021-04-01',
               '2021-05-01',
               '2021-06-01',
               '2022-02-01',
               '2022-03-01',
               '2022-04-01',
               '2022-05-01',
               '2022-06-01'],
     'PCE': [  1.695549, 1.706421, 1.692806, 1.863354, 1.911975,
               6.274030, 6.638595, 6.269216, 6.324989, 6.758935]}

pce = pd.DataFrame(d)
pce = pce.set_index('Date')
pce.index = pce.to_datetime(pce.index)
```

You could create a new dataframe with a copy of the datetime index as a new column, [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) the new dataframe with annual frequency ('A') and [count](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.count.html) all unique values in the Date column.

```
pce_annual_rows = pce.index.to_frame()
resampled_annual = pce_annual_rows.resample('A').count()
```

Next you can get the second last Date-count value and use that as your periods values in the pct_change method.

The second last, because if there is an incomplete year at the end, you probably end up with a wrong periods value. This assumes, that you have more than 1 year of data in every dataframe, otherwise you'll get an IndexError.

```
periods_per_year = resampled_annual['Date'].iloc[-2]
pce['ROC'] = pce['PCE'].pct_change(periods_per_year)
```

This produces the following output:

```
                 PCE       ROC
Date
2021-02-01  1.695549       NaN
2021-03-01  1.706421       NaN
2021-04-01  1.692806       NaN
2021-05-01  1.863354       NaN
2021-06-01  1.911975       NaN
2022-02-01  6.274030  2.700294
2022-03-01  6.638595  2.890362
2022-04-01  6.269216  2.703446
2022-05-01  6.324989  2.394411
2022-06-01  6.758935  2.535054
```

This solution isn't very nice, maybe someone comes up with another, less complicated idea.

To build your for-loop to do this for every dataframe, you'd probably better use the same column name for the columns you want to apply the pct_change method on.